# App crashes when loaded after user presses back button

Tags: android, storage

I am writing one of my first apps where the idea is that user inputs a number into a getText, clicks a button which adds the users input to previous results and shows this to the screen. I've tried storing the data in SharedPreferences and it works when the user presses the home button and then comes back into the app, but the app crashes if they press the back button and then comes back into the app. Any advice?

```
public class Calc extends Activity {

int points = 0;

SharedPreferences data;
public static String filename = "Points";

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    data = getSharedPreferences(filename, 0);

    points = data.getInt("key", 0);

    final TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.mytextview);

    myTextView.setText("" + points);

    Button Button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.add);
    final EditText Edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input);

    Button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            int temp = 0;

            try {
                temp = Integer.parseInt(Edit.getText().toString());
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                System.out.println("Could not parse " + nfe);
            }

            points = points + temp;

            if (points > 9999) {
                myTextView.setText("10000+");
            } else {
                myTextView.setText("" + points);
            }

            Edit.setText("");

            SharedPreferences.Editor editor = data.edit();
            editor.putInt("key", points);
            editor.commit();
        }
    });

}
}
```

crash log:

```
05-19 03:24:02.352: D/dalvikvm(1120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 759 objects / 55808 bytes in 63ms
05-19 03:24:05.812: D/dalvikvm(1120): GC_EXTERNAL_ALLOC freed 193 objects / 9224 bytes in 50ms
05-19 03:24:08.842: W/KeyCharacterMap(1120): No keyboard for id 0
05-19 03:24:08.842: W/KeyCharacterMap(1120): Using default keymap: /system/usr/keychars/qwerty.kcm.bin
05-19 03:24:11.052: W/IInputConnectionWrapper(1120): showStatusIcon on inactive InputConnection
05-19 03:24:14.952: E/dalvikvm-heap(1120): 16704000-byte external allocation too large for this process.
05-19 03:24:14.999: E/GraphicsJNI(1120): VM won't let us allocate 16704000 bytes
05-19 03:24:15.022: D/AndroidRuntime(1120): Shutting down VM
05-19 03:24:15.061: W/dalvikvm(1120): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example/com.example.Calc}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class <unknown>
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:513)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneLayoutInflater.onCreateView(PhoneLayoutInflater.java:56)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:563)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:385)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:320)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:276)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.setContentView(PhoneWindow.java:198)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.Activity.setContentView(Activity.java:1647)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at com.example.Calc.onCreate(Calc.java:32)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     ... 11 more
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:79)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:446)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:500)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     ... 21 more
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.nativeCreate(Native Method)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:468)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createBitmap(Bitmap.java:435)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.graphics.Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(Bitmap.java:340)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.finishDecode(BitmapFactory.java:488)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:462)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeResourceStream(BitmapFactory.java:323)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.graphics.drawable.Drawable.createFromResourceStream(Drawable.java:697)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:1709)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:601)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:1885)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.view.ViewGroup.<init>(ViewGroup.java:291)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.<init>(FrameLayout.java:83)
05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120):     ... 25 more
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:paddingLeft="25dip"
        android:paddingRight="25dip"
        android:src="@drawable/title" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/input"
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/add"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:text="Add Points" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/youHave"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:background="#AA968454"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:text="You have"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytextview"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:background="#AA968454"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#ffffffff"
        android:textSize="60dp" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: where is CalcActivity Activity code

Comment: Do you really have a layout file named 'main'  in your res/layout ?

Comment: How big are your images 'background' and 'title'? (image sizes in width & height please)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im guessing you have an image on your activity. Thats what

> "05-19 03:24:15.223: E/AndroidRuntime(1120): Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap >size exceeds VM budget

Try using a smaller image or refer to
[Strange out of memory issue while loading an image to a Bitmap object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/477572/android-strange-out-of-memory-issue-while-loading-an-image-to-a-bitmap-object/823966#823966) for an alternate solution.

I'd first recommend you remove your imageview to check if this is the problem. If the problem is rectified look at the solution in the link above.